# Client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a couple of tasks running as a service. To kick off the **worker** I use:

```
def SvcDoRun(self):
    logging.info('Starting {name} service ...'.format(name=self._svc_name_))
    os.chdir(INSTDIR) # so that proj worker can be found
    logging.info('cwd: ' + os.getcwd())

    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)

    command = '{celery_path} -A {proj_dir} worker -f "{log_path}" -l info --hostname=theService@%h'.format(
        celery_path='celery',
        proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
        log_path=os.path.join(INSTDIR,'celery.log'))

    logging.info('command: ' + command)

    args = shlex.split(command)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)

    logging.info('pid: {pid}'.format(pid=proc.pid))

    self.timeout = 5000

    while True:
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            print 'Terminate'
            # stop signal encountered
            PROCESS_TERMINATE = 1
            handle = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, proc.pid)
            win32api.TerminateProcess(handle, -1)
            win32api.CloseHandle(handle)
            break
```

To kick off the python **tasks** as a service I use:

```
def SvcDoRun(self):
      import servicemanager
      servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, ''))

  self.timeout = 640000    #640 seconds / 10 minutes (value is in milliseconds)
  # This is how long the service will wait to run / refresh itself (see script below)

  while 1:
     try:
        # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
        # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
           # Stop signal encountered
           servicemanager.LogInfoMsg(self._svc_name_ + " - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
           break
        else:
           #[actual service code between rests]
           try:
              file_path = "C:\framework\celery\celery.py"
              execfile(file_path)             #Execute the script

           except Exception as exc:
              traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
           #[actual service code between rests]
     except Exception as exc:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

The 'celery.py' contains the call to those tasks as follow celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(include=[
             'framework.task1.tasks',
             'framework.task2.tasks',
             'framework.task3.tasks',
             'framework.task4.tasks'
             ])

app.config_from_object('config')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

***The problem*** I call a task '`python runTask1.py param1 param2 param3`' but sometimes the task never executes then I send it again (or twice) and it works... Looking at the rabbitmq log file I saw:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::00:57:37 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3846.0> (127.0.0.1:57753 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::00:57:37 ===
connection <0.3846.0> (127.0.0.1:57753 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::00:58:08 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3871.0> (127.0.0.1:57821 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::00:58:08 ===
connection <0.3871.0> (127.0.0.1:57821 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::01:10:49 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.3940.0> (127.0.0.1:57861 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::01:10:49 ===
connection <0.3940.0> (127.0.0.1:57861 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

=WARNING REPORT==== 24-Jun-2017::01:10:49 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.3940.0> (127.0.0.1:57861 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Why sometimes it works and sometimes it does not?

Comment: did you find the reason that this is happening? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had not but, are you also using a script to run celery as a service?

Comment: no, I'm using pika. I figure out a few reasons that it is happening but still didn't solve the problem completely, what I've done was to write a small script that just pushes hello to the queue and I realised that when it reaches to 1000 message per second it drops the connection, another thing was when the message size gets bigger. so  when rabbitmq doesn't have enough RAM or CPU it will drop the connection, it is also mentioned in documentation.

Comment: I have a similar problem with pika, any news on this?
How did you fix it?